# Perl script for generating MAC addresses

Tags: perl, mac-address

This perl line very useful to change mac address but retain the first three pair.

```
perl -e 'for ($i=00;$i<6;$i++){@m[$i]=int(rand(256));} printf "00:16:3E:%X:%X:%X\n",@m;'
```

Generate some good address

```
00:16:3E:1E:B6:DB
00:16:3E:EE:8D:4A
```

But some with only one figure(E,D)

```
00:16:3E:80:21:D
00:16:3E:18:87:D
00:16:3E:E6:EF:5
00:16:3E:E:99:6A
```

I want all with two figures,for example the bad 
become

```
00:16:3E:80:21:D1
00:16:3E:18:87:4E
00:16:3E:E6:EF:5A
```

How to do?

Comment: That's because you're printing without leading zeroes, so `D` isn't printed as `0D`. Use the `%02X` format specifier to force it to print as zero-padded two digits hex number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution seems to work: `%X` become `%02X`

Old and not working

```
perl -e 'for ($i=00;$i<6;$i++){@m[$i]=int(rand(256));} printf "00:16:3E:%X:%X:%X\n",@m;'
```

new and working

```
perl -e 'for ($i=00;$i<6;$i++){@m[$i]=int(rand(256));} printf "00:16:3E:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",@m;'
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but when you present a command line in an answer that is almost 100 characters long and is almost the same as the command line in the question,  it’s nice to *say* what you changed, and not force us to get out our magnifying glasses and compare them character-by-character.

Comment: Ok,I will correct it now